# Text doesn't wat to sit under z-Index

Tags: html, css, z-index

I am having trouble to explain my issue, but here goes...
I have create a z-index layer effect and want to some words to show up underneath. This sounds simple right, however my text goes and sits underneath the "Z-Index layers".

How do I correctly markup my text to "Inherit" or to sit under the Z-Index.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Please Code below:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>2013 Christmas Ecard</title>



 </head>

<body onload="init();" style="background-color:#D4D4D4"><p>

<font face="Arial">From all of us at Canadian Western Trust.<br><br>

<canvas id="canvas" width="711" height="661" style="z-index: 3; position: absolute; background-color:#ffffff"></canvas>


  <!--[if IE]><param name="movie" value="______.SWF"><![endif]-->
  <!-- fallback to Flash: -->

    <object id="top" style="z-index: 2; position: absolute" width="711" height="661" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" value="_____">
        <!-- Firefox uses the `data` attribute above, IE/Safari uses the param below -->
        <param name="movie" value="________.SWF" />
    </object> 



    <img id="under" style="z-index: 1; position: absolute" src="______"> 


<font face="Arial">
    Please view in HTML.<br><br>
   We wishes everyone a wonderful holiday season and a happy new year!<br><br>

    Please click <a href="____" target="_blank" title=" Christmas animation card">here</a> to open the e-card in your web browser.
    <br><img src="{Campaign_Opened Email_Tracking_URL?}">
</font>

    <br>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<div position: absolute; top: 699px;>` isn't exactly valid HTML OR css... Make sure your HTML is 100% valid before you start debugging.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I realized that, guess it's result of me trying everything.

Comment: create a fiddle maybe to show a working copy of your issue

Comment: PLEASE SEE fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dawidspamer/yTYDA/

Comment: You'll see the text sticking out on the right-hand side. That needs to go underneath the image.

Answer (score 0):

There seemed to be some open  tags that was floating around. WoW!! THat gave me a head ache. All good now and works!

```
<body onload="init();" style="background-color:#D4D4D4"><p>


<font face="Arial">From all of us .</font><br><br>




            <canvas id="canvas" width="711" height="661" style="z-index: 3; position: absolute; background-color:#ffffff"></canvas>


          <!--[if IE]><param name="movie" value="...."><![endif]-->
          <!-- fallback to Flash: -->

        <object id="top" style="z-index: 2; position: absolute" width="711" height="661" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" value="https://...">
                <!-- Firefox uses the `data` attribute above, IE/Safari uses the param below -->
                <param name="movie" value="https://...." />
        </object> 



        <img style="z-index: 1; position: absolute" src="https://...."> 
 <font style="position: absolute; top: 725px;" face="Arial">
    Please view in HTML.<br><br>
    We wishes everyone a wonderful holiday season and a happy new year!<br><br>

    The greatest gift is our children.....<br><br>

      Please click <a href="https:"" target="_blank" title="Christmas animation card">here</a> to open the e-card in your web browser.
    <br><br><img src="{Campaign_Opened Email_Tracking_URL?}">
    </font>
<br>


</body>
```